# obtain joined rows from hclust using cutree

Tags: r

I use code along those lines:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzywuzzyR)
library(proxy)
library(stringdist)

set.seed(42)
rm(list = ls())
options(scipen = 999)

#init = FuzzMatcher$new()

data <- data.frame(string = c("world hello", "hello world", "hello vorld", "hello world 1", "hello world", "hello world hello world"))
data$string <- as.character(data$string)

distance_function <- function(string_1, string_2) {
    #init$Token_set_ratio(string1 = string_1, string2 = string_2)
    stringdist(string_1, string_2, method = "qgram")
}

combinations <- combn(nrow(data), 2)
distances <- matrix(, nrow = 1, ncol = ncol(combinations))

distance_matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(data), ncol = nrow(data), dimnames = list(data$string, data$string))

for (i in 1:ncol(combinations)) {

    distance <- distance_function(data[combinations[1, i], 1], data[combinations[2, i], 1])

    #print(data[combinations[1, i], 1])
    #print(data[combinations[2, i], 1])
    #print(distance)

    distance_matrix[combinations[1, i], combinations[2, i]] <- distance
    distance_matrix[combinations[2, i], combinations[1, i]] <- distance

}

hclust <- hclust(dist(1 - distance_matrix), method = "ward.D2")

plot(hclust)
```

I can order the strings 'one dimensional' using:

```
hclust$labels[c(hclust$order)]
```

I would also like to append the information of the strings being joined according to the dendrogram that can be produced using:

```
plot(hclust)
```

I am aware of cutree but it feels not right here (e.g. using the h parameter or k). Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
rapply(as.dendrogram(hclust), function(x) attr(x, "label"), how = "list")
# [[1]]
# [1] "hello world hello world"
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "hello vorld"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [[2]][[2]][[1]]
# [1] "hello world 1"
#
# [[2]][[2]][[2]]
# [[2]][[2]][[2]][[1]]
# [1] "hello world"
#
# [[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]]
# [[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[1]]
# [1] "world hello"
#
# [[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]][[2]]
# [1] "hello world"
```

which gives you a nested list.